# How to get coordinates of distance below 1500m in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

There different lat long position of restaurant from firebase. Get data from model class namely cameraid, lat and long.

here is the code used for getting lat long from firebase:

```
  func loadCameraLocation() {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("camera").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")

                let cameraLocation = camera.transformNotification(postDictionary: document.data())

                self.cameraLatString = cameraLocation.cameraLat
                guard let latValue = self.cameraLatString else { return }

                let latDouble = Double(latValue)

                print("cameraLat:::-\(String(describing: self.cameraLatString))")
                self.cameralongString = cameraLocation.cameraLong


                guard let longValue = self.cameralongString else { return }

                let longDouble = Double(longValue)

                print("cameraLong:::-\(String(describing: self.cameralongString))")


                let dict: [String: Any] = ["cameraLat": latValue, "cameraLong": longDouble]

                self.calDistance(lat: latDouble!, long: longDouble!, item: camera.transformNotification(postDictionary: dict) )


            }
        }
    }


}
```

And calculating distance of user current lat long from camera lat long to get nearest restaurant and show to multiple marker annotation in mkmapview.

Here is the code i tried for calculating distance of below 1500m:

```
func calDistance(lat: Double, long: Double, item: camera ) {


    guard let searchlatValue = self.searchedLat else { return }

    let searchlatDouble = Double(searchlatValue)

    guard let searchlongValue = self.searchedLong else { return }

    let searchlongDouble = Double(searchlongValue)


    self.cameraIDLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

    self.userSearchedLocation   = CLLocation(latitude: searchlatDouble!, longitude: searchlongDouble!)

    let distance = (self.cameraIDLocation?.distance(from: self.userSearchedLocation!))!

    print(String(format: "The distance to driver is %.01fkm", distance))


    if (distance <= 1500) {

 //            let artwork = self.multipleMarker.append(distance)

       let locationDtaa = cameraData.append(item)


        print("artwork:::\(locationDtaa)")


        //                            driverArray.append(item)

        //                            let artwork = Artwork(title: title, locationName: locationName, discipline: discipline, coordinate: coordinate)



    }


}
```

Model class of camera data:

```
 class camera {
var cameraLat: String?
var cameraLong: String?
var cameraLocationName:String?

}
extension camera {
static func transformNotification(postDictionary: [String: Any]) -> camera {
    let cameraid = camera()

    cameraid.cameraLat = postDictionary["cameraLat"] as? String
    cameraid.cameraLong = postDictionary["cameraLong"] as? String
    cameraid.cameraLocationName = postDictionary["cameraLocationName"] as? String



    return cameraid
}
```

}

My question - How to get lat long, camera title, camera id of below 1500m. Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: What's your problem? Your code looks good.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa print("artwork:::\(locationDtaa)") getting empty.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa here i need to get printed lat long of less than 1500m

Comment: You need to print("artwork:::\(cameraData)") not `locationDtaa `

Comment: Because `append` method does not return value.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa i just want add multiple marker annotation in mkmapview based on lat long less than 1500m. could you help me out of this pls..

Comment: @KosukeOgawa i have included model class data in my question and values are getting from firebase

Comment: What is outputted? : `print(String(format: "The distance to driver is %.01fkm", distance))`

Comment: @KosukeOgawa The distance to driver is 1237.7km and print("artwork:::\(String(describing: cameraData.last?.cameraLat)), \(String(describing: cameraData.last?.cameraLong))") output:   artwork:::Optional("12.9010"), nil

Comment: @KosukeOgawa any update??

Comment: Why `cameraData.last?.cameraLong` is nil? I think it's cause.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa dont know

Comment: @KosukeOgawa hey now i am getting coordinate array. here is what i tried markerLatLong.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)) in console i got output like this artAppend:::[__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.901, longitude: 80.227900000000005), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.889799999999999, longitude: 80.227999999999994)]

Comment: @KosukeOgawa now to set multiple marker in mkmapview